# What is the call order of oncreateoptionsmenu() in the android activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, oncreateoptionsmenu

Is `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of action bar called before or after the `onStart()` of activity?

Comment: Put a `Log.v(...)` message in each function to find out

Comment: A real easy way to tell would be to put a breakpoint or log in each and see which happens.

Comment: Can you put some sample code illustrating where you feel the function isn't behaving appropriately?

Comment: `OnStart`

`OnResume`

`OnCreateOptionsMenu`

Answer (score 8):

onStart() is called first. (I tried putting log messages in the methods).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found this order to be the correct one

`onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()- onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: I believe it's quite mind and app-breaking. I though in onStart I can access everything already. And looks like originally onCreateOptionsMenu was called somewhere during or after onCreate

Answer (score -2):

This is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).

This is written in the Android documentation.

Comment: onPrepareOptionsMenu is not called every time menu is to be displayed anymore. onInvalidateOptionsMenu()  is required to call onCreateOptionsMenu() and onPrepareOptionsMenu() Jelly Bean onwards (except the first time ofcourse). This also makes me think onPrepareOptionsMenu() is pretty much useless, unless someone can give an example of a use-case to me.